# Splitting CSV cell values with python

Tags: python, csv

I am pretty new to coding with python but I've manage to create a csv for inventory purposes. I am having some trouble trying to accomplish this particular task however.

Basically I have a csv like this:

headers - `product name, sizes, qty`

row 1 -`item1, var1 var2 var3 var4, 2 4 6`

row 2 -`item2, var1 var2 var3 var4, 2 4 6`

But I would like for the csv to basically show like this:

headers - `product name, sizes, qty`

row 1 -`item1, var1, 2`

row 2 -`item1, var2, 4`

row 3 -`item1, var3, 6`

row 4 -`item2, var1, 2`

row 5 -`item2, var2, 4`

row 6 -`item2, var3, 6`

I've tried splitting the sizes and qty cells sending it to a list and then creating a new csv with the values only but how can I do this on the same csv I'm creating the first time where the values are coming out this way?

Comment: what about `var4`? Please show your code and explain exactly what's wrong with it. At this stage I don't understand your problem...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use split on values and create desired csv file :

```
name = 'var1 var2 var3 var4'
size = '2 4 6 '

n = name.split()
['var1', 'var2', 'var3', 'var4']

s = size.split()
['2', '4', '6']
```

csv.writer(item,n[0],s[0])

Comment: Thanks, this makes sense. I will give this a shot.